# How do I pass username password to Fuji Xerox printer APEOS Port II 7000?

Tags: drivers, printing

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and have been printing on a Fuji-Xerox printer model APEOS Port II 7000, that is until they started implementing username / password login for the printer. This is not SMB password rather the password on the machine.

I have tried setting the URI as something like this:

```
DeviceURI lpd://01:0001@192.168.2.49/PASSTHRU
```

where "01" and "0001" are my username and password on the printer to get it to print but then to no avail. The error that appears on the printer is that I am not authorized. Can someone who have had experience with this kind of printer please chime in ?

Comment: Required some post (http) action for login and print or ([?](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-printing-smb-printer.html)).

Comment: it's not http. The authentication is at the printer itself. It tries to authenticate at the printer.